# Yii multiple commit transaction in loop

Tags: yii, transactions

I have very big transaction which executing 1h, maybe is possible in loop start and commit transaction multiple ?

Because if I get some error in finish it's not save all new record.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Perhaps show some code so we will understand. Only note that you cannot nest transactions. In addition if your program fails before you commit your transaction, you will lose your data.

Comment: Maybe savepoints helps you, It depends of your db engine; in framework, iterator combined with savepoints can help you if you are using many active record objects